# Using $GLOBALS[] variable in PHP class function

Tags: php, class, variables, global

I'm trying to assign `$GLOBALS['a']` variable in function from class, but haven't succeeded.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

 $GLOBALS['a'] = "alter";

 class db_data 
 {
   public $a;

   function __construct()
   {
     $this->a = $GLOBALS['a']; 
   }

 }

 $db = new db_data;

 echo $db->$a;

?>
```

And produced this error:

> Notice: Undefined property: db_data::$alter.....

I tried to search on SO for this, but all questions were different and it did not resolve my problem.

Comment: echo $db->$a;
or echo $db->a; remove $

Comment: To access an object's properties, you need `echo $db->a;`

Comment: stop using globals or stop using class, by using one you negate the benefit of the other.

Comment: ((( always same error - syntax/inattention. Thanks a lot! ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers are in the question comments, but here's why it's happening

You're accidentally using the [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) feature of PHP. When you call `$thing->$a`, you're actually getting the value of $a (which defined by the `$GLOBALS['a'] = "alter";` line), and then getting the property of `$thing` with that value.

As stated in your comments, you should simply echo `$db->a`, as that's [how PHP properties are accessed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Also, **Watch out!**, if the value of `$a` is changed elsewhere in the global scope, your db_data class will reflect that change, which you probably don't want.

Comment: Thanks, For watch out - thats exactly what i need. if it changes, i want to use it.

Comment: another thing if i'm asking - what difference between -> and :: ?

Comment: The double colon, called the [Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php), is for referencing [static properties or methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) on a class. Basically, a static method/property is just attached to a class, rather than in instance of that class.

In my opinion, the error message should show `->` instead of `::`, but it's PHP.